# Tikzpictures side by side with same axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to create a figure where three tikzpictures are aligned side by side, where each plot should have the same axis alignment. I tried it in the following way

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz-cd} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=-1/3,ymax=1.3,
 xmin=-1/3,xmax=1,
 axis line style={draw=none},
 ticks=none,xlabel=$K_1$
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{0.02}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\oo}{1}    
\draw[black,fill=red,opacity=\oo] (0,0) circle (\rr) node[below] {$v_1$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.3cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=-1/3,ymax=1.3,
xmin=-1/3,xmax=1,
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none, xlabel=$K_2$
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{0.02}    
\pgfmathsetmacro{\oo}{1}    
\draw[black,fill=red,opacity=\oo] (0,0) circle (\rr) node[below] {$v_1$};
\draw[black,fill=red,opacity=\oo] (3/4,3/4) circle (\rr) node[below] 
{$v_2$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{0.3cm}
\begin{minipage}{0.15\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin=-1/3,ymax=1.3,
xmin=-1/3,xmax=1,
axis line style={draw=none},
ticks=none,xlabel=$K_3$
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{0.02}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\oo}{1}
\draw[black,fill=red,opacity=\oo] (0,0) circle (\rr) node[below] {$v_1$};
\draw[black,fill=red,opacity=\oo] (3/4,3/4) circle (\rr) node[below] 
{$v_2$};
\draw[black,fill=red,opacity=\oo] (1/2,1) circle (\rr) node[below] {$v_3$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\caption{test}
\label{fig: test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output:

[image]

As you can see the alignment doesn't work at all. It somehow shifts everything to the right and also the tikzpcitures itself overlap.

Could somebody please explain me how to do this in a proper way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). As it is we have to hunt around and guess what packages etc you are using. A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Comment: The empty line between first and second minipage allows the line break.  Don't leave empty lines between aligned minipages. Instead of minipages you could also use `shifted scopes` inside the same `tikzpicture` environment.

Comment: @Andrew Now it should be compileable.

Comment: @Ignasi Deleting the empty line doesn't change anything at the ouput. I will take a look at shifted scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what you want the output to look like, so I don't know if the output below is what you want, but one possibility is to use only one `minipage` (or even no minipages) and to put everything inside one `tikzpicture` environment with the different graphs inside different`scope` environments. Doing this produces:

[image]

As I said, I have no idea if this is the output you want:)

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}% not needed?
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\rr}{0.02}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\oo}{1}

\pgfplotsset{
  myaxis/.style={
    ymin=-1/3,
    ymax=1.3,
    xmin=-1/3,
    xmax=1,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    ticks=none,
  },
}
\tikzset{
  bline/.style= {
    black,
    fill=red,
    opacity=\oo
  }
}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=0\textwidth]%  not needed, only for consistency
      \begin{axis}[myaxis, xlabel=$K_1$]
          \draw[bline] (0,0) circle (\rr) node[below] {$v_1$};
      \end{axis}
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=0.3\textwidth]
      \begin{axis}[myaxis, xlabel=$K_2$]
        \draw[bline] (0,0) circle (\rr) node[below] {$v_1$};
        \draw[bline] (3/4,3/4) circle (\rr) node[below] {$v_2$};
      \end{axis}
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[xshift=0.6\textwidth]
      \begin{axis}[myaxis, xlabel=$K_3$]
        \draw[bline] (0,0) circle (\rr) node[below] {$v_1$};
        \draw[bline] (3/4,3/4) circle (\rr) node[below] {$v_2$};
        \draw[bline] (1/2,1) circle (\rr) node[below] {$v_3$};
      \end{axis}
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\caption{test}
\label{fig: test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have cleaned up your code a bit. It helps to define the `tikz` and `pgfplots` styles that you use separately and then just plug them in when you need them. This make the code much more readable and, importantly, much easier to tweak and change as you only need to do this in one place.

Comment: Thx for your help. With this I should be able to create the plot I was hoping for :).

Comment: @Squeezelemma Glad it was useful!